# SonarQube - average from all projects

Tags: sonarqube, analytics, sonarqube5.1

I am searching for SonarQube plugin that gives me an average(average complexity, average loc...) from all my projects. We need it to compare single projects with the average.

Has anyone a solution or a plugin with this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the commercial [Views plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it :)